# How to get number of node of particular content type?

Tags: nodes

I have one content type as "refund",
I want all number of node of this content type according to month wise, year wise and per day. I can get total number of nodes of refund content type by query but how to get sorted by month wise, year wise and per day wise and then show through views?

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I want total number of nodes of particular content type sortable by month wise, year wise and per day wise

Comment: Also relevant: [How to get a count of number of nodes created per month in views](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31523/how-to-get-a-count-of-number-of-nodes-created-per-month-in-views)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the node number (and I wouldn't reccomend it). This is a unique number used by Drupal.

You could set the content type to have a date field, and then use the auto path module to pull this data into the URL. This information would also then be usable by Views.

If you want to count the number of nodes of that content type then use [Serial Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial) - that will also be accessible to URL alias and views. Details from its project page:

> Unlike Drupal's built-in auto-increment node ID, which is global and shared by nodes belonging to all content types, serial fields are managed per content type (D6) / entity (D7). For example, the serial field of an Invoice instance will generate a unique sequential number (starting at 1, then 2, etc.) exclusively for Invoice instances.
>
> The allocation of serial numbers by this module is atomic. In other words, the serial values are unique even when multiple instances of the same content type / entity are created simultaneously.

Brief explanation but can provide more step by step detail if you want.

Comment: I don't want to change node number
I just want total number of nodes of particular content type sortable by month wise, year wise and per day wise then want to show through views

Comment: Then use the serial module above and use place a date field in the content type. The serial will count the number of of nodes of that content type, and then the date field will give your date values for sorting.